# how does pipe work

Tags: csh, tcsh

explain me please how exactly pipe works, for example I have this snippet of the code

```
set line = ($<)

while(${#line} != 0)
 if(${#line} == 5) then 
  echo line | sort | ./calculate ${1}
 endif 
 set line = ($<)
end
```

I need to choose all rows with 5 words and after sort it and after transfer, but I'm confused, how will it work, first of all 'while' will take all information and after that transfer it to sort, or every iteration 'while' will do sort? thanks in advance

Comment: removed tags "programming-languages" and "programming" because the first isn't relevant to the question and the second is so general it should apply to every question on SO.

Comment: `echo line` throughout this discussions should be understood as `echo $line` as we need the value of the variable, not the word "line".

Answer (score 3):

In the event that the OP cares about internals, a pipe is often implemented as circular buffer. That is the OS puts aside a chunk of memory and keeps track of what segment of it is currently in use (wrapping around from the end to the beginning as needed):

```
+-------+
| front |
+-------+
      |             +-------+
      |             | back  |-------\
      V             +-------+        V
+---+---+---+---+---+      +---+---+----+---+---+---+
|   | c | o | n | t |  ... | e | r | \n |   |   |   |  // the buffer itself
+---+---+---+---+---+      +---+---+----+---+---+---+
```

And we control the behavior with these rules:

- The wrap-around behavior is accomplished by doing *all* the position arithmetic modulo the buffer length (watch out if our language uses 1 indexed arrays!).
- If `front` and `back` are ever the same (as in the starting condition), then the pipe is empty and attempts to read from it will block until there is something to read.
- If `back` is `(front-1)` (modulo the length, remember!), the buffer is full and attempts to write will block until there is room.
- Reading a value from the pipe returns the contents at `front`, and advances front by one.
- Writing a value to the pipe advance `back` by one and inserts the new input at this location.

---

More complicated schemes involving allowing the buffer to grow when there is a need *and* memory is available are possible (and indeed are common), and the above can be simplified by make the buffer itself only one character long (meaning that we don't even need front and back anymore) but you pay a cost in terms of a lot of locking and many unnecessary context switches.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're running the `echo line | sort | ./calculate ${1}` command in every iteration, it will run separately each time through.  A pipe just takes the output of the command on the left and feeds it to the input of the command on the right.

Comment: Wooble: how can I pick ALL information and after that transfer it to sort and after to uniq?

Comment: can I do only echo, and after script ./calculate, inside ./calculate, I'll write sort | uniq...?

Comment: You can probably do all of this within one script, although it would almost certainly be easier in any language except [t]csh; see http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/

Answer (score 1):

A pipe is something that reads an input from and produce an output at the same time, for example you could have a pipe that takes in an input composing of lower-case letters, the pipe will modify (without changing the original source of input, such as a data file) the input data and change it to upper-case letters.

Pipes are processed in the left to right fashion.

```
echo line | sort | ./calculate ${1}
```

`line` is piped into `sort`. `Sort` then sorts the input data and outputs data, which in turn is piped into a `calculate` process which is expecting some input.

It might be easier to visualise this in this way, think of it as a tube or plastic pipe (rain gutter variety):

```
INPUT <---+---> OUTPUT
          |
         pipe
```

***Edit:***

Since your original question asked to interpret the code snippet, which is based on the C Shell, without further ado...

```
1. set line = ($<)
2. while(${#line} != 0)
3. if(${#line} == 5) then 
4.  echo line | sort | ./calculate ${1}
5. endif 
6. set line = ($<)
7. end
```

1. Takes the input from standard input, or from file (this can be done by redirecting file into this script by doing 'this_script < data file' or 'cat data_file | this_script'.
2. While loop to read until EOF is reached (in Unix/Linux variants, its Ctrl+D, for Windows, its the F6 Key)
3. If the line count has reached 5, i.e. the first 5 lines, that's the part that is bothering me and am not 100% confident on...but will carry on to explain further..
4. The 5 lines are echo'd to output, but because of the pipe, the output become an input into sort, in turn sort then reads from that input, sorts the data and is outputted, but then again, because of yet another pipe, calculate takes in the input from the sorted output.
5. Sets the variable `line` to contain more input. and re-loops around.

And to answer your comment, you can tack on the pipes if you wish, I will highlight line 4 as shown:

```
echo line | sort | uniq | ./calculate ${1}
```

Feel free to play around with the combination, by the way, I think that `line` should be `$line` if my memory serves me correct?

Comment: tommieb75: in my case can I do only echo, and after script ./calculate, inside ./calculate, I'll write sort | uniq...?